# Matrix Random Path With certain length

Tags: c#, matrix, path-finding

I have a matrix with size N*M, I need to write an algorithm to find a random path (the path is always less than N*M) from a random starting point, the endpoint does not matter, what matter is the length of the path should have a certain length.

assume that this function is already implemented:

`getRandomNeighbor(Point x);`
which returns a random available neighbor or null if there are no available neighbors around that point which causes a stuck state.

What I've done so far is this:

```
 private HashSet<Vector2> GeneratePath()
    {
        Vector2 currentLocation;
        HashSet<Vector2> path = new HashSet<Vector2>();
        pathGenerated = false;
        do
        {
            pathGenerated = true;
            int randXIndex = Random.Range(0, board.Count);
            int randYIndex = Random.Range(0, board[randXIndex].Count);
            currentLocation = new Vector2(randXIndex, randYIndex);
            path.Add(currentLocation);
            foreach (Word word in RingsGameManager.Instance.wordsToUse)
            {
                foreach (char letter in word.word.Replace(" ",""))
                {
                    if (!GetNextLocation(currentLocation, path, out currentLocation)) // the insides of this if statemenet should change!!
                    {
                        pathGenerated = false;
                        break;
                    }
                    path.Add(currentLocation);
                }
                if (!pathGenerated) break;
            }
            if (!pathGenerated) path.Clear();
        } while (!pathGenerated && !stopGenerating);

        return pathGenerated ? path : null;
    }
```

the function tries to generate a path blindly trying randomly each time which is very wrong I know, it just "WORK" in the mean time.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Could you add the code you have got so far?

Comment: I've added what I've done so far, however, it's very inefficient.

Comment: Could I ask what's `RingsGameManager.Instance.wordsToUse`?

Comment: What do you mean by `length`, is it the number of segments in the path, or the sum of the lengths of the segments?

Comment: sorry for the late response, so basically the path is gonna be the length of some words, in short, each character is gonna be in a cell in the matrix, so the length of the path is the sum of all characters in all words, and the words are in RingsGameManager.Instance.wordsToUse. I hope this clarifies the question more.